# Ubuntu Server 14.04 on VirtualBox - GPG error NODATA (All Previous Threads Unhelpful)

Tags: 14.04

Error screen-shot:

[image]

I am having issues with `apt-get update`, running it on VirutalBox. Getting an error, it is in the link included.

```
GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I am on a VirtualBox, using a Netgear AP(using it as a bridge with ddwrt), hitting a Linux wrt110, network looks good. able to ping out on the vmOS, 
I have read some stuff on the ISP blocking the traffic (so setup a vpn to another ISP that I know isn't blocking it)

Honestly I think it is either the VirtualBox or something with the ppa's.

Any advice, excuse the new question, because previous questions have all resulted in failure to resolve my issue.

Comment: Provide information as text rather than image(s) (readable, searchable, etc).

Comment: If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing packet traffic and testing vBox settings for NAT, NAT Network, bridged adapter, Internal Network, Host-Only Adapter and Generic Adapter.

Using Bridged Adapter and pointing to my NIC (network interface card) (in the picture) `eth0` was still holding the old NAT settings. Restarted OS, dhcp pulled the new Bridged Adapter Settings. Everything works now.

What I did:

- Change Attached to: Bridged Adapter (in virtualbox)
- Restart the Virtual Machine (vbox)
- preferable using Ubuntu OS rather than a hard reset
- `root#WebServer:/home# shutdown -r now`

[image: Settings]